# QGIS 3.2: Where are layout files stored?

Tags: qgis-3, layout-manager

I am changing computers at work and I want to be able to bring all of my old layouts (the ones accessed through the layout manager) over to my new computer. Each layout is set up on a particular location in the exact place I want it. If I have to recreate these in the future, I don't think I could make them 100% the same and I would have to redo hours of work.

I searched through the QGIS files and I didn't see anything that was definitely the save point for each layout.

Does anyone know where these are saved?

[image: Image of my custom layouts as shown in the Layout manager]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are stored within your qgis project file (`.qgs` or `.qgz`). So changing your computer will have no effect on your layouts. Just open the QGIS-Project file on your new computer and they will be there.

You can open .qgs files with a texteditor and search for `Layouts` if you want to take a look at them. However, .qgz files are packed and need to be unzipped first.

Here's a screenshot of the .qgs file with the layout stored:

[image]

You can also export your layout as a template:

[image]

Comment: Ah! Fantastic. I didn't even consider that they might be a part of the project file. Thank you so much for your concise and thorough answer.

Comment: @MrXsquared If your project in the QGZ format, just unzip this file, then you will have the QGS file in it.